# how to print second row as second column unix

Tags: unix

How can I print every second row as tab delimited second column like below. thanx in advance.

input

```
wex
2
cr_1.b
4
```

output

```
wex 2
cr_1.b 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option that doesn't depend on the length of lines:

```
awk '{ if (NR % 2 == 1) tmp=$0; else print tmp, $0; }' <filename>
```

If you really want a tab separator, use `printf "%s\t%s\n",tmp,$0;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no blank lines in your input file, this should do the trick:

```
awk 'length(f) > 0 { print f $0; f = "" } length(f) == 0 { f = $0 }' file
```

Comment: It is working fine but it is giving weird output when the name in 1st row is longer. For ex; wex-12233hhbhdhbx. Thanx